# Is good practice to prefix ALL classes/interfaces/functions with the App acronym?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working in an Angular project, and I would like to know if is good practice to **prefix** all Classes, Interfaces & Functions with the **App acronym**.

For example, is well standardized to prefix tag components with the App acronym, so it will not collide with other items in the dom and will be easier to search.

So for example if my app acronym is toh (Tour of Heroes), and I have a filter component, its tag would be `<toh-filter>`.

This is totally fine, but, is a good practice to apply that to **ALL** the codebase?
For all the codebase I mean: all Classes, Interfaces & exported functions and constants.

I would like to understand the **Pros & Cons** and why it could make sense or not.

**Note** that this application will not be consumed for other apps as a library or so. All the components, service, utilities will be used internally in the same app.

Here are some examples (without prefix & with prefix):

```
// ./filter.component.ts
@Component() export class FilterComponent {}
@Component() export class TohFilterComponent {}

// ./some.service.ts
export class SomeService {}
export class TohSomeService {}

// ./utils.ts
export function deepCopy() {}
export function tohDeepCopy() {}

export function pipe() {}
export function tohPipe() {}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would it be good practice to add meaningless, redundant text everywhere?

Comment: Is there a difference between `deepCopy` and `tohDeepCopy`? If so, a different name makes sense. But adding prefixes for no reason doesn't.

Comment: @Flimzy off-topic, I agree, this should be on another stack exchange. Opinionated, well the framework is, so you can answer accordingly. Obvious, for you & me maybe, but apparently not for him, hence the justification that he can ask it to learn why it's not needed. And [don't forget that !](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback)

Comment: @Flimzy things that you think are obvious aren't for other people. I am just trying to find enough arguments to demonstrate that this approach is bad. I have joined an entire codebase that is made like that, and I would like to change it... but isn't easy to convince the other people that this is the good way. I need strong arguments

Answer (score 3):

I would say no.

When you write TS/JS code that is splitted throughout multiple files, you have the ability to choose from where to import you classes, and even rename them.

So you can manage conflicts on your own, without the need to add the prefix.

As you might have seen, Angular appends a suffix to your classes : this is because of their LIFT style requirement that says a file/class/var/etc. should be found & identified very quickly.

But for the prefix, it's not needed, and the main con of that is you will have to do it by hand on every class you write, while there isn't any pro to it.

So to sum it up, no, you should not.